# C - fgets() produces gibberish

Tags: c, malloc, fgets

I use VS 2010 as my IDE and this code works fine until the line where fgets is called as a puts argument. It writes down the numbers in the file fine but it also prints some annoying gibberish. Maybe I am missing a \0 somewhere, dunno. Other people tried it on other compilers like mingw or gcc and it works fine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *a, n, i;
    char str[512];
    FILE *f;
    printf("Insert array size: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    if(n <= 0)
    {
        printf("%d is not an allowed value!\n", n);
        return 1;
    }
    a = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(a == NULL)
        return 2;
    putchar('\n');
    f = fopen("myarray.txt", "r+");
    if(f == NULL)
        return 3;
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Insert %d. element of the array: ", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        fprintf(f, "%d ", a[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    puts(fgets(str, 512, f));
    free(a);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Don't cast the result of malloc in C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1202636).

Comment: I thought type conversion in c is explicit? Is it not so?

Comment: Have you read the accepted answer of the linked question?

Comment: So this is valid only when I am casting a void *, otherwise it's fine? Just realized I mixed it up with C++, damn.

Comment: Almost, conversion to _and from_ `void *` to any object pointer is implicit and safe, otherwise you have to add a cast (and pay attention to do a safe cast).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point in your code where you call `fgets` your file pointer should be at the end of the file.

Thus, [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) should be returning you the `NULL` pointer, since it hits EOF before reading any characters.

Thus, you're passing the `NULL` pointer to [`puts`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/puts/).

Comment: So rewind(f) should resolve it I guess if I call it before fgets?

Comment: Really, you should probably check `ferror` after `fgets` and before `puts` or you could end up with a really hard to debug problems.

Comment: It's just a school assignment so it is not necessary imho. It seems that rewind is working, thank you.

Comment: Not enough reputation of my own, sorry. I need 15 rep points. Or are you talking about the yes/no question at the bottom? Excuse me, I am new around here.

Comment: You only need 15 rep points to upvote something. To accept it, you just click on the check mark that appears under the voting arrows

Comment: Just did, sorry it took me so long.

Comment: Even if dereferencing a `NULL` pointer is undefined behavior and everything could happen, isn't it strange that the program doesn't crash? Doing this resulted in some kind of memory error on almost every system I tried since the null pointer usually points to an area that is always invalid.

Comment: Why would the area be invalid - you mean not allocated or already in use by an other process? That would imply a run-time access violation I guess, but it just didn't happen, not once.